# Does TTURLRequest handle timeouts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

If my connection hangs, is there a way to set a timeout for TTURLRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the timeout is hardcoded in TTURLRequestQueue.m:

```
static const NSTimeInterval kTimeout = 300.0;
```

I really wonder why this is.

Answer (score 2):

The kTimeout constant is the initial time constant. You can configure the timeout by following:

```
[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue].defaultTimeout = 30; //in case you want 30 seconds
```